# Different ways to display images in ASP.NET MVC and when to use which approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a website using ASP.NET MVC4 to upload/display images and found a few ways of how to display images, chiefly the below -

**1)** Store the image as a file locally on the server and use a relative path to display it on the page.

```
 //ImageFile is a property which holds a path to the image in the model
 <img src="@item.ImageFile" />

 When the page is rendered, this becomes a path like - <img src="/Content/Images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
```

**2)** Store the image as a byte array and retrive it using a controller action -

```
//Use a controller action (GetImg) to get the URL of the image
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImg", "ViewPhotos", new { id = item.ID })" alt="Image" />  

When the page is rendered, this becomes a path like - <img src="/ViewPhotos/GetImg/4" alt="Image" />
```

**3)** Store the image as a byte array and retrive it in the view directly -

```
//Directly re-construct the image in the view from the byte array (Image property of the model)
<img src="@String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image))" />  

When the page is rendered, this becomes a path like - <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEA....<long string> .../>
```

My questions are -

*1) What is the difference between 1 and 2 ?*

1 directly provides the path to file and 2 provides a URL to it. Are they the same in the background or is one approach better than the other?

I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759189/how-does-url-action-work-asp-net-mvc) and it says that - Url.Action will construct the path to the action, returning a url, not the results of executing the action. So when are are results retrieved?

*2) Does it makes a performance impact when 3 is used against 1 or 2?*

*3) Which approach should be used when image sizes are small (less than 1MB) or large ?*

Happy if you can point to me any links which can be of help as well.
Thanks.

Code -

//Model

```
public class Photo
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string ImageFile { get; set; }
  public byte[] Image { get; set; }
  public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

//Controller

```
public FileContentResult GetImg(int id)
{
    byte[] byteArray = db.Photos.Find(id).Image;
    if (byteArray != null)
    {
        return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg");
    }
    else
    {
         return null;
    }
}
```

//View (approach 2)

```
@model IEnumerable<MyPhotoLibrary.Models.Photo>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
  <td>
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImg", "ViewPhotos", new { id = item.ID })" alt="Image" />
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

//View (this is approach 3)

```
@model IEnumerable<MyPhotoLibrary.Models.Photo>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
  <td>
    <img src="@String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image))" />
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I looked this up myself recently, and came across the Microsoft research paper [To BLOB Or Not To BLOB](https://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525), which compares the performance of storing files (such as images) as binary data in a database to that of a conventional filesystem.

The findings, roughly summarised:

- small files (sizes > 256KB) are best stored as byte arrays in the database (your second and third options), from which they can be retrieved quickly and served to the user.
- Large files (sizes > 1MB or so) are best stored in a filesystem (your first option) because the throughput and fragmentation of large database blobs deteriorate sharply with larger files
- between 256KB and 1MB (roughly; the range is fuzzy and depends on your exact setup) performance depends on how many times the files are likely to be edited or overwritten; in general the database performs better with static files while the filesystem is considerably better at maintaining high throughput and low fragmentation with files that change frequently.

Other differences between the options:

**Option 1** requires your application to have read permissions on whichever folder the images are in, and if the images are being uploaded or edited by users, then the application will need write permissions on that folder as well. This may be tricky if you're on shared hosting (especially on cheap or free hosting plans) or if your sysadmin is particularly paranoid.

**Option 2** requires more calls from client to server to get all the data; this may look like a bad thing but it does break up the pageload into chunks which might actually help - the page (without images) will load on the first call, and then the images will be requested separately, If one of them takes a while, or has some sort of error, then the rest of the page should be unaffected, which is nice. As [jgauffin pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855556/different-ways-to-display-images-in-asp-net-mvc-and-when-to-use-which-approach/16856113#comment24309842_16856113) in the comments, this option allows you to set up caching for the images, so browsers can save bandwith by only re-downloading them when they've changed.

**Option 3** requires the client to load the whole lot in one, which may take a while. It also shifts the processing of the byte array onto the client, which may be a problem on low-powered clients like smartphones or low-end netbooks. If your images are large it may be better to use the server's CPU power to actually handle the conversion from byte array to image file. As [jgauffin notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855556/different-ways-to-display-images-in-asp-net-mvc-and-when-to-use-which-approach/16856113#comment24309842_16856113) in the comments, this also doesn't play nicely with caching - if any part of the view's HTML changes, browsers will have to download the images again

Also, this may not be relevant to your specific situation but having the images loaded by a separate call lets you do other things in those actions, like writing to debug logs or doing some other housekeeping behind the scenes.

Comment: +1 Option 2 is better than Option 3 since image caching is hard in the latter as the cache will be invalidated every time that the view is changed (or the image itself). Base64 would also require some additional processing

Comment: Yeah, caching is also worth mentioning. In option 2, browsers will recognise that they're making a GET and getting an image, which they can cache and reuse across multiple pages; in option 3 they only see massive base64 strings which they have to process.

Comment: About store images in file or database you can see http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-filestream-performance/ and as you said http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525 and about which type of calling images from view i agree with you on approach 2 because of its caching and load into chunks. but i don't know about how could affect performance by ultra count of hitting server when it hadn't cache. Can you absolutely advise that?

Answer (score 2):

1) will have less processing on the server-side, as there will be less function calls. if you want to render the output of the action - you need to call HTML helper method Html.RenderAction or Html.Action more on the [differences here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)

2) the difference between 2 and 3 is that when you input the byte array directly, you have less round trips to the server (DNS look-ups and such), but more data to download in a single request. Some browsers,  may download content in parallel (5-8 parallel downloads per domain), so if you use 3, you loose in terms of page loading speed. more on paralel downloads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723810/max-number-of-concurrent-file-downloads-in-a-browser) and [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26753/why-do-big-sites-host-their-images-css-on-external-domains)

and that leads us to 3) if you have small images, 3 is the way to go, as the client will request less resources, and the page will load faster, but if you have large images, you should use 1.

Comment: Thanks Igarioshka. Its much clear now. So for small images I can use 3 and for large images I can use 1. But when should I prefer 2 over 1?

Comment: @siddharth well, you use 2 if you have a set of images and you want to  globally customize the way they are rendered, or apply custom logic (role validation of some sort). 2 is basically an added functionality, as you may implement both 1 and 3 through a call to an action

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the time to test performance but I will keep you a couple of points.

In approach 1 you are indeed relying only on HDD storage and performance to keep the files and on your web server capabilities of delivering static files.

In approach 2, you are generating the bytestream everytime there is a request... The storage and retrieval is DB driven (HDD plays a role of course), and you cannot leverage the native caching capabilities of the web server without adding some relevant code (which may be just an attribute `OutputCache` but it can be more complex).

In approach 3, the client is just rendering and you are sending the image together with the web page. Here performance really depends on the browser but keep in mind that it will take some time to receive the whole page if the image is very big.

So I would generally prefer approach 1, I only have to store an image path in the db and then I can get the image from disk and let IIS do the caching, delivering, optimization etc.

There are a lot of valid reasons to go for approach 2, which is mainly if you have a ditributed web servers architecture, where approach 1 means that each server has to hold a copy of the image on the HDD, while having everything in one place in the DB means you can retrieve the iamges whenever you want... Maybe implement a bit of caching to avoid hitting the DB in each request.

Approach 3 is really only for single use small images. I say single use because you would not like to use this for icons and images used all around, these should stay static so they can be cached by the client.

Hope that helps making a better decision.

In a scenario similar to 2, with a multiple web server architecture, in a past job we went for a mixed solution: the images were on the DB but each single web server, on the first request after hitting a 404 for the image, would download the image from the DB and instruct the client to retry (which is, in a way, a very raw implementation of caching).