# JS files async loading in the right way. How to?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have couple of `CDN` files what I call in header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.2/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and after all my js files what are depending on this libraries,
but google's page speed complains that those scripts are blockers on page load. So I tried to put everything before body closing but in this case I will have all scripts broken because they depend on jquery.

I tried to use `defer` but like that the same problem as in footer. How do I load async javascript libraries to not break the hole?

Comment: there must be something else wrong, jquery wouldn't break

Comment: could you please share the console logs as well?

Answer (score 2):

General solution is to use async module load like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). Here's a jQuery integration case: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Considering "but in this case I will have all scripts broken because they depend on jquery." you could add check in your JS code like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //your jQuery-based code
})


//if jQuery loading failed
if(!window.jQuery){

}
```

Comment: there are a lot of scripts included I just want to optimize the page load not to refactor the hole code

Comment: i've listed to ways - refactor with AMD or quick patch with ```!window.jQuery```.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the number of files from the same host. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/723891/26049).

Answer (score 0):

What you would like to achieve is **AMD** *(Asynchronous Module Definition)*

> Asynchronous module definition (AMD) is a JavaScript specification that defines an API for defining code modules and their dependencies, and loading them asynchronously if desired.
>   *Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition*

There are a bunch of frameworks for that:

- RequireJS - http://requirejs.org
- Dojo Toolkit - https://dojotoolkit.org

Or you can load JS files manually, using this method *(not recommended)*:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719185/1502230